# Http Basic Auth with RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64 in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently working with and API that requires "RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line" this seems to be different from the normal basic auth used in the requests library. Curious if anyone else has come across this and been able to solve it? I imagine I will have to write a function to do this encoding and build the header manually.

Comment: AFAICT that description matches the standard format for the content of the `Authorization` header used in HTTP Basic Authentication, and the `requests` library constructs the header using exactly that format.  What leads you to believe that there's an incompatibility here?

Comment: I discovered this when trying to authenticate to a server using basic auth, and just could not get it. So the reason why I think they are using different standards is the requests library docs [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/requests/auth/) uses the base64 library then if you check the base64 library docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) they claim to use RFC 3548. If I manually try to generate the token with base64 I get a totally different token from what I know works. I had to go to an online encoder to get the correct token to move on.

Comment: That's very strange.  The base64 algorithm and alphabet are the same in RFCs 3548 and 2045. The differences between those RFCs have to do with line length (which is ignored in Basic Auth) and the treatment of non-base64 characters if they occur in an encoded string (which should not happen in Basic Auth).  Can you edit the question to show an example of how you tried to manually generate the token and how your generated result differs from the desired (working) result?

Comment: I apologize but I think I wasted your time. I tested the base64 library on my home computer and it spit out the correct string. The API I was hitting at work constantly kicked it back with an auth failure. I must have been incorrect in my original belief, I must have been doing something wrong. I will have to test again later but I no longer think the issue is the requests library. Thank you for looking into it though!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to hear that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a function as shown below where the headers for the request are created manually.

For this implementation, you will need these variables:
`API_PUBLIC_KEY`,
`API_SECRET_KEY`,
`host_url`,
`endpoint` (where the API is supposed to hit).

```
import base64
import requests

def create_request():
    auth_header = base64.b64encode(bytes(f'{API_PUBLIC_KEY}:{API_SECRET_KEY}'.encode('ascii'))).decode('utf-8')
    headers = {
        'Host': host_url,
        'Authorization': f'Basic {auth_header}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    api_endpoint = f'https://{host_url}/{endpoint}'
    data = {}
    response = requests.request("POST", api_endpoint, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```